# SideKiq para multiplos domínios

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho  um servidor de produção que conterá vários clientes, e quero adicionar o [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) para gerenciar as filas de processamento de imagem. Porém,  não sei como é o comportamento dele para múltiplos domínios, ou seja, cada sistema terá uma fila ou todos os sistemas concorrerão a uma fila em especial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem 2 opções.

Usar no mesmo redis, usando uma fila para cada app

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#queues

Ou usar um redis para cada app ( obviamente rodando em porta diferente ).

Eu trabalho com o 1 caso, mas deste modo, dentro do admin do sidekiq de todos os apps você verá todas as filas, se isso for um problema use um redis para cada.